# How to use SELECT query based on method parameter in Flask restplus Api?

Tags: python, mysql, select, peewee, flask-restplus

I want to handle a `GET` request in my `Flask REST API`.The request will include `List` parameter and I use this to be a typical GET request:

`https://localhost:5000/organisation?List=1`

this request, will return all of `Organisation` Model information. `Organisation` is a Model class for a table of my MySQL database(by `peewee`).

I want to enter `PrivenceId` parameter in request and will return all of `Organisation` Model information where `Organisation.PrivencedId == PrivenceId` parameter, But I encounter the following Error:
`TypeError: 'Organisation' object is not iterable`

my code (`OrganisationController.py` file) is:

```
from flask_restplus import Resource, reqparse
from Models.Organisation import Organisation
from flask import request

# Define parser and request args
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('List', type=int)
parser.add_argument('ProvinceId', type=int)

class List(Resource):

    def get(self):

        args = parser.parse_args()
        List = args['List']
        ProvinceId = args['ProvinceId']      

        if  List :
            Organisations = Organisation.select() 

            Ls = [dict (
                 ID = c.ID,
                 Title = c.Title,
                 Code = c. Code,
                 OrgEnumId = c.OrgEnumId,
                 ProvinceId = c.ProvinceId, 
                 CityId = c.CityId,
                 Address = c.Address,
                 Phone = c.Phone,
                 ) for c in Organisations
                ]

            return dict(Organisations = Ls)

         elif (ProvinceId) :
            Organisations = Organisation.select().where
                             (
                             Organisation.ProvinceId ==args['ProvinceId']
                             ).get()

            Ls = [dict (
                 ID = c.ID,
                 Title = c.Title,
                 Code = c. Code,
                 OrgEnumId = c.OrgEnumId,
                 ProvinceId = c.ProvinceId, 
                 CityId = c.CityId,
                 Address = c.Address,
                 Phone = c.Phone,
                 ) for c in Organisations
                ]


            return dict(Organisations = Ls)
```

and `boot.py` file for run api is :

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_restplus import Api
from Controllers import OrganisationController


app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(OrganisationController.List, '/organisation')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run ('127.0.0.1', 5000, True)
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this line of my code and solved my problem:

```
Organisations = Organisation.select().where
                         (
                         Organisation.ProvinceId ==args['ProvinceId']
                         )
```